# IE (again) messes up template, float problem

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I'm coding my template and everything works and shows well in Chrome and Firefox, but again... Internet Explorer messes the whole thing up.

I tried looking for solutions but I'm stuck here.

Here is a [link](http://taxade.vazcreations.nl) to the website. If you can look at it real quick in chrome/firefox and then in IE you know what I mean and maybe you can find the problem.

Thanks!

Coding is pretty much like this:

```
<div id="leftbox">
left content
</div
<div id="rightbox">
right content
</div>
<div id="mainbox">
center content
</div>

#leftbox {float:left;}
#rightbox {float:right}
#mainbox {width:xxx; backgroun...}
```

Comment: have you set a doctype? Renders fine in IE9...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the `float:right` from `#rightcolumn` and everything "snapped into place".

Comment: Thanks m8! Can't believe I din't saw that. Great great!!

Answer (score 0):

Place all #main... blocks into one wrapper. In example #maincolumn don't have floated elements around, so it acts like it is cleared.